# I want to create a asp.net webapplication for multiple monitors

Tags: asp.net, multiple-monitors

I am creating a webapplication in asp.net. This application has to be shown on multiple monitors (every screen with the same lay-out, but a different content). I can make sure that the user does use a specific browser like google chrome. Is this possible and how can i do it?

for example, i want a label in monitor 1, a other label in monitor 2 and a other label in monitor 3.

Comment: You're going to face some difficulty with this as, depending on the browser that you use, you will probably be unable to open a web page in anything but what the user has set their pop-up options to show (i.e. windows or tabs).  Also, what have **you** tried so far?  On SO we won't do your work for you - show us what you've done and why you're stuck and then people will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the user's machine with your webpage - you cannot know where the user places their browser window, how big it is, on which monitor it is, etc.

If you need such fine control, consider creating a click-once type of desktop application that will connect to your server for data.